# Get updated value of x-editable after save

Tags: javascript, jquery, x-editable

What do I need to call to get the updated value of the text returned by x-editable?  There is a table of numerous values that when changed should then change the color of a progress bar.  After the text value of GroupCurrentHPi is changed, I want to update the color of a progress bar HPProgressBari based upon it's value.

I was using $(this).text() but that seems to only grab the value before the change and not after the change.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {    
    
    $('#GroupUserData').DataTable();
 
    $.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'popup';                      
    $.fn.editable.defaults.url = 'Post.php';            
    $.fn.editable.defaults.responseTime = 200;                  

    var GroupMembers = document.getElementById("GROUPCOUNTVAL").value;

    if (GroupMembers>0) {
        for (i = 0; i < GroupMembers; i++) { 
            $('#GroupCurrentHP' + i).editable({
                name: 'selected_hp'                
            });
          
            $('#GroupCurrentHP' + i).on('save', function(e, params) {             
               updateColor("#HPProgressBar" + i,$(this).text());
            });            
        }
    }
    
function updateColor(progressBar, value){
    
    if(value > 100) {value = 100}
    if (value == 100) {$(progressBar).css({'background-color': "#006600"})}
    if ((value > 75) && (value < 100)) {$(progressBar).css({'background-color': "#4dff4d"})}    
    if ((value > 50) && (value < 75)) {$(progressBar).css({'background-color': "#FA6539"})}    
    if ((value > 25) && (value < 50)) {$(progressBar).css({'background-color': "#F6A942"})}    
    if ((value > 0) && (value < 25)) {$(progressBar).css({'background-color': "#CF6363"})}    
    if (value < 0) {$(progressBar).css({'background-color': "#FF0000"})}
    
}

});
```

Comment: What is the value of `c` that your passing to `updateColor`?  I don't see it being set anywhere.

Comment: Sorry I must have it a button overtop of  the code, it should have been ,$(this).text().  I updated the post.

Comment: Thanks.  That code is only running once on `$(document).ready`, do you call `updateColor()` anywhere else in the code?

Comment: Not yet, I don't have it running anywhere else.  I made it a function just in case I might, I very well could just insert that inline instead but that doesn't fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
$('#GroupCurrentHP' + i).on('save', function(e, params) {             
  updateColor("#HPProgressBar" + i, params.newValue);
});
```